# Is Cargo able to infer multiple versions of the same library?

Tags: rust, build, dependencies, dependency-management, rust-cargo

Let's say there is a library `fancy_math`.

`fancy_calculus 1.0` depends on `fancy_math 1.8`.

However, due to some breaking changs introduced in `fancy_math 2.0`,  `fancy_calculus 1.0` can only depend on `fancy_math 1.8`.

There's also a library `fancy_physics 1.0` that is built upon `fancy_math 2.0`, and will not work with earlier versions.

With Cargo, if I wanted to use both `fancy_calculus 1.0` and `fancy_physics 1.0`, will Cargo be able to infer that I need both `fancy_math` versions `1.8` and `2.0` and build them separately? Is there some namespace-mangling done?

Comment: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/dependency-resolution-with-multiple-versions/81936

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the Cargo reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#semver-compatibility):

> If multiple packages have a common dependency with semver-incompatible versions, then Cargo will allow this, but will build two separate copies of the dependency. For example:
>
> ```ini
> # Package A
> [dependencies]
> rand = "0.7"
>
> # Package B
> [dependencies]
> rand = "0.6"
> ```
>
> The above will result in Package A using the greatest `0.7` release (`0.7.3` at the time of this writing) and Package B will use the greatest `0.6` release (`0.6.5` for example). This can lead to potential problems, see the [Version-incompatibility hazards](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#version-incompatibility-hazards) section for more details.

However, as specified in the "Version-incompatibility hazards" section, you will not be able to use types of `fancy_math` that `fancy_calculus` exports where a type of `fancy_math` that `fancy_physics` exports is expected, or the opposite.